# Ionic2 button must stick to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, ionic2

Can you tell me how to fixed a button bottom of the page? At this moment it stays end of the item list.I need to set the button stays on the bottom of the page(or screen) while the user can scroll the items.I'm using Ionic2.

[**Plunker is here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/iuQgXs)

**page1.ts**

```
    <ion-content padding class="page1">
      <ion-list no-lines>
        <ion-item class="background-color-light-gray">
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <h2 color="primary">My Event</h2>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  <div class="fixed-outside">
    <button ion-button block>Donate</button>
  </div>,
    })
```

css

```
.fixed-outside {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            height: 120px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use ion-footer, for example

```
<ion-content></ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
     <button ion-button block>Donate</button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: Great.Thanks a lot :)